# Inheritance in nested classes C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, nested

fans of beautiful code.

I would like to ask my question by two ways. May be it will be useful to understand me.

1) There is code of 2 classes. One of them is nested. Nested class is used to get access to private fields of other one. I would like to get inherit class B:A{class BUnit:AUnit{}} which has the same functional but else has some more methods and fields in B and BUnits classes. How it can be done?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Add();
        a.Add();
        a.Add();
        bool res=a[0].Rename("1");//res=true;
        res = a[1].Rename("1");//res= false;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class A
{
    private List<AUnit> AUnits;
    public AUnit this[int index] {get {return AUnits[index];}}

    public A()//ctor
    {
        AUnits = new List<AUnit>();
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        this.AUnits.Add(new AUnit(this));
    }

    public class AUnit
    {
        private string NamePr;
        private A Container;
        public AUnit(A container)//ctor 
        {
            NamePr = "Default";
            this.Container = container;
        }
        public string Name { get { return this.NamePr; } }
        public Boolean Rename(String newName)
        {
            Boolean res = true;
            foreach (AUnit unt in this.Container.AUnits)
            {
                if (unt.Name == newName) res = false;
            }
            if (res) this.NamePr = String.Copy(newName);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

2) There is two very similar “things” – Class A and Class B. Is it possible to separate their common part, and then “inherit” this two “things” from it ?  For example, I would like add some methods like GetUnitsCount() or RemoveUnit() and this methods are common for both. So I should “CopyPaste” this method to A and B but it is not good idea. It will be better to change their common part one time in one place. There is no important how it can be done – inheriting or interfaces or anything else. Important - how?

```
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Add();
        a[0].objB.Add();
        a[0].objB.Add();
        a[0].objB[0].Val1 = 1;

        int res = a[0].objB[0].Val1 + a[0].objB[0].Val2;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class A
{
    private List<AUnit> Units;
    public AUnit this[int index] {get {return Units[index];}}

    public A()//ctor
    {
        Units = new List<AUnit>();
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        this.Units.Add(new AUnit(this));
    }

    public class AUnit
    {
        private string NamePr;
        private A Container;
        public B objB;
        public AUnit(A container)//ctor 
        {
            NamePr = "Default";
            this.Container = container;
            this.objB = new B();
        }
        public string Name { get { return this.NamePr; } }
        public Boolean Rename(String newName)
        {
            Boolean res = true;
            foreach (AUnit unt in this.Container.Units)
            {
                if (unt.Name == newName) res = false;
            }
            if (res) this.NamePr = String.Copy(newName);
            return res;
        }
    }
}


class B
{
    private List<BUnit> Units;
    public BUnit this[int index] { get { return Units[index]; } }

    public B()//ctor
    {
        Units = new List<BUnit>();
    }
    public void Add()
    {
        this.Units.Add(new BUnit(this));
    }

    public class BUnit
    {
        private string NamePr;
        private B Container;
        public int Val1{get;set;}
        public int Val2{get;set;}
        public BUnit(B container)//ctor 
        {
            NamePr = "Default";
            this.Container = container;
            this.Val1 = 10;
            this.Val2 = 17;
        }
        public string Name { get { return this.NamePr; } }
        public Boolean Rename(String newName)
        {
            Boolean res = true;
            foreach (BUnit unt in this.Container.Units)
            {
                if (unt.Name == newName) res = false;
            }
            if (res) this.NamePr = String.Copy(newName);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attentions.

Comment: this code looks wrong `foreach (AUnit unt in this.Container.AUnits)
            {
                if (unt.Name == newName) res = false;
            }` are you missing a break? Is it simply `bool res = !this.Container.AUnits.Any(unt => unt.Name == newName)`?

Comment: Looks like yes. But this part of code is only for example how I would like to use private field.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the only thing you need to to to have `BUnit` inherit from `AUnit` is to *qualify* `AUnit`:

```
public class BUnit : A.AUnit
{
    ....
}
```

from there I believe your question is about basic inheritance which works no differently for nested classes.  Nested classes are purely for organization - they are not inherited when you inherit the "containing" class.

Comment: Class A (from first part of my question) used type of class AUnit in own methods. Inheritor of AUnit will have other type. Is it important? Could you give me example of inheritance for this case and example of using it? I mean something  [main()] B b=new b(). b[0].e=1; where is e is new field (property) in BUnit.

Comment: Yes - you _might_ be able to make a generic subclass (e.g. `Unit<T> where T:A`) but it's not completely clear.  Side note - what do you expect the "nested" class idiom to gain you over separate classes?

Comment: Actually, for my tasks that is possible to use separate classes without any nested. But now that is just interesting (for me) question - how to do it using nested classes.

Comment: There's no difference from an inheritance standpoint between nested classes and non-nested classes.

Comment: D Stanley, thank you for your advice. Now I understand that the main problem is not "nested". But I still don't know how modify Class A from first part of question and how I can create class B inherit from A. Should I create other question (topic) or may be you can show me example here? How for example modify method Add() using <T>...?